# Vb.net code to toggle the page between 2 gridviews automatically using timer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have 2 gridviews in a single aspx page were I want second gridview to be displayed after first gridview after 5 seconds and vice versa automatically(without manual intervention)

NOTE: I don't click on any button while i have to load this page. This should work on page load.

Currently I am able to display the second gridview2 after 5 sec of gridview1 display but I'm unable to switch back to first gridview1 automatically.
Kindly need your inputs on this please!

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

       <asp:Panel id="panel1" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="Purple" BorderStyle="Double" CssClass="auto-style2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Algerian" Font-Size="XX-Large" Height="1200px" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center" PageSize="15">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectName" HeaderText="Project Name" SortExpression="ProjectName" ItemStyle-CssClass="FrozenCell" HeaderStyle-CssClass="FrozenCell">
                <ControlStyle Font-Bold="False"   Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Calibri" ForeColor="#FFFFDF"  />
                <HeaderStyle ForeColor="#FF9999" CssClass="FrozenCell" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="XX-Large"  />
                </asp:BoundField>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="ReqBy" HeaderText="Requested By" SortExpression="ReqBy">
                <ControlStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Calibri" ForeColor="#FFFFDF" />
                <HeaderStyle ForeColor="#FF9999" />
                     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="XX-Large" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
                <ControlStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Calibri" ForeColor="#FFFFDF" />
                <HeaderStyle Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="#FF9999" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="XX-Large" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompletionPerc" HeaderText="Completion Percentage" SortExpression="CompletionPerc" >
                <ControlStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Calibri" ForeColor="#FFFFDF" />
                <HeaderStyle ForeColor="#FF9999" />
                     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="XX-Large" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" HeaderText="Start Date" SortExpression="StartDate">
                <ControlStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Calibri" ForeColor="#FFFFDF" />
                <HeaderStyle Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="#FF9999" />
                   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="XX-Large" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Deadline" HeaderText="Deadline" SortExpression="Deadline">
                <ControlStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Calibri" ForeColor="#FFFFDF" />
                <HeaderStyle Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="#FF9999" />
                     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="XX-Large" />
                </asp:BoundField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SoneilCloudRemConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ProjectName], [Status], [ReqBy],[StartDate],[CompletionPerc], [Deadline] FROM [ProjStatusDisplay] ORDER BY [Priority]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </asp:Panel>

    <div id="secondgrid">
             <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" ontick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="5000"></asp:Timer>
     <asp:Panel id="panel2" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%">

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="Purple" BorderStyle="Double" CssClass="auto-style2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Algerian" Font-Size="XX-Large" Height="1200px" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center" PageSize="15">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectName" HeaderText="Project Name" SortExpression="ProjectName" ItemStyle-CssClass="FrozenCell" HeaderStyle-CssClass="FrozenCell">
                <ControlStyle Font-Bold="False"   Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Calibri" ForeColor="#FFFFDF"  />
                <HeaderStyle ForeColor="#FF9999" CssClass="FrozenCell" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="XX-Large"  />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ReqBy" HeaderText="Requested By" SortExpression="ReqBy">
                <ControlStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Calibri" ForeColor="#FFFFDF" />
                <HeaderStyle ForeColor="#FF9999" />
                     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="XX-Large" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectManager" HeaderText="Project Manager" SortExpression="ProjectManager">
                <ControlStyle Font-Bold="False"  Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Calibri" ForeColor="#FFFFDF" />
                <HeaderStyle ForeColor="#FF9999" />
                     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="XX-Large" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompletionPerc" HeaderText="Completion Percentage" SortExpression="CompletionPerc">
                <ControlStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Calibri" ForeColor="#FFFFDF" />
                <HeaderStyle ForeColor="#FF9999" />
                     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="XX-Large" />
                </asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SoneilCloudRemConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ProjectName], [ProjectManager], [ReqBy], [CompletionPerc] FROM [ProjStatusDisplay] ORDER BY [Priority]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
      <asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" ontick="check_Tick" Interval="10000"></asp:Timer>   
     </asp:Panel>            
     </div>         

</form>
```

vb code

```
Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    GridView2.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to refresh the data in the grids every 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes I am refreshing the data in every 5 sec.

Comment: Ok, you should read up on the [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.timer.interval?view=netframework-4.8) and the example they have on the page. When your timer ticks you also need to set the display of the grid you want to show and hide,

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example you can try. It will give you a basic idea how this could be achieved.

**DEMO**

[image]

**Code Snippets**

Markup

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
        <div style="display: flex;">
            <div style="margin-right: 20px;">
                <h4>GridView1</h4>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>GridView2</h4>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
        <div style="height: 200px; overflow-x: auto; margin-top: 10px;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

VB Code

```
Private Property gridNo As Integer
    Get

        If Not IsPostBack Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(HiddenField1.Value) Then
            HiddenField1.Value = 1.ToString()
        End If

        Return Integer.Parse(HiddenField1.Value)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        HiddenField1.Value = value.ToString()
    End Set
End Property

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        BindGrid(1)
        BindGrid(2)
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    BindGrid(gridNo)
    Dim textColor As String = If(gridNo = 1, "green", "blue")
    Label1.Text = String.Format("<span style='margin-bottom: 5px; display: block;color:" & textColor & "'>GridView{0}.DataBind()</span>", gridNo)
    gridNo = If(gridNo = 1, 2, 1)
End Sub

Private Sub BindGrid(ByVal gridNo As Integer)
    Select Case gridNo
        Case 1
            GridView1.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(Function(x) New With {
                Key .CurrentTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(x).TimeOfDay
            })
            GridView1.DataBind()
        Case 2
            GridView2.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(Function(x) New With {
                Key .CurrentTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(x).TimeOfDay
            })
            GridView2.DataBind()
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Could anyone help me out using Javascript to swap the grids automatically using timer?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use a VB timer for this.**

That will force you to rebuild that grid data and do a full HTTP request/response cycle on each tick. Instead use javascript to swap between the grids, where both were rendered into the same HTML page once.

You can cycle between them using any slideshow or carousel script on the containing div.

Comment: Hi Joel,  I was thinking on using Javascript because of the drawbacks but was stuck on how to use them between the 2 grids. Could you please provide a code snippet for this ?

Comment: Hi Joel, Could you please share your ideas or code snippet on how to perform swap between grids automatically using javascript? 
I have tried initially using javascript but unable to use timer and gridviews simultaneously.

Comment: There are as many ways to do this as there are programmers in the world. What will work for you will depend too much on how the rest of the page is put together, what other javascript tools you may have available, and many other factors. I will say you should stop talking about using a timer and either start thinking in terms of javascript's `setTimeout()` function or in terms of using a pre-built javascript carousel or slideshow widget.

Comment: Thanks Joel, further to proceed. I have added div tag for both the gridviews and then tried to use javascript but unable to proceed as there is something wrong with the Javascript function. Need guidance on that please.
  <script>
        var time = 3000;
        function changegrid() {
                       var first = document.getElementById("firstgrid");
                        setInterval("first", 3000);
            var second = document.getElementById("secondgrid");
           // second.innerHTML();  }
        setTimeout("changegrid()", time);
    </script>

Comment: It would be great if I get some more details interms of Javascript as I am not finding any solution.